# What does the "Invoke" action on a lambda function refer to?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I have a policy that allows the *Invoke* action on a function. I tried to invoke this function using `lambda.invoke()` (using the aws javascript sdk) and got a 403 to say that I did not have permissions to perform the action `InvokeFunction` on the function. I then changed my policy to allow `InvokeFunction` (and removed `Invoke`) and only then was I able to invoke the funtion.

If allowing *Invoke* does not give permissions to invoke a function, then what does it allow you to do.

Comment: I'm looking at the list of IAM permissions for Lambda [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-api-permissions-ref.html) and I only see `lambda:InvokeFunction`. I think `Invoke` was invalid and was simply being ignored.

Comment: @MarkB I can believe that. Though it is strange that that action would show up in the list of actions in the policy im. See [this](https://imagebin.ca/v/3ijhh9I7hxq0)